# Optional stopping theorem for backwards martingales

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

> Is there a optional stopping theorem for backwards martingales  ?

When $T$ is a non-positive and bounded stopping time then what kind of random variable is the following,

$\{X_{-T\wedge n}\}_{n\le-1}\tag1$

Is there a typo ? It doesn't make sense to me because $n$ is negative and $-T$ becomes positive ?

I should actually show if $\{X_k\}_k$ is a backward martingale with respect to backward filtration then so is $(1)$